# How do I get my toddler to stop waking at 4am?

Tags: toddler, sleep

My 12 month old has been waking at 4-4:30 am for quite some time. He usually doesn't require anything to go back to sleep but just wakes crying and grizzly. Sometimes I go in and give him his dummy other times he still has his dummy so I just lay him back down and he goes back to sleep until about 7am. I cannot work out why he is waking at this time and how to get him to just sleep through.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting SE:) When do you put him to sleep? Isn't he hungry? Any diaper "events" at that time? At what time does the sun rise? Do you have some kind of blinds, maybe drapes?

Comment: His bed time routine is good. He eats dinner about 6pm and is in bed at 7. There is not usually any "diaper events" and it is usually still dark when he wakes and his room is at the back of the house and has blinds so is dark pretty much all day. I thought he might be hungry at first too but he has dinner and a bottle before bed and when he wakes at this time he goes back to sleep without me feeding him and doesn't need breakfast until about 7.

Comment: I've marked this as duplicate, because based on the information here, the answers on the older question seem likely to adequately cover it. If you feel the other answers don't apply to your situation, please provide more information and flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

He may be going through a growth spurt and waking hungry, or he may wake, and sensing separation from you, need to be reassured you are there. What you will find with babies, and indeed children as they grow throughout the time they are with you, is that their sleep patterns keep evolving and changing. What is troubling you now, in a few months time will be replaced by something new. I think you are doing exactly the right things! Until he is verbal, you cannot know for sure, so comforting him for a few moments and helping him back to sleep seems exactly right. His waking pattern is certainly not abnormal.